# 'boost::operator ==' : 4 overloads have similar conversions

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors

The code below gives me a compile-time error. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this or what might be causing it?

> 'boost::operator ==' : 4 overloads have similar conversions

```
typedef boost::function<void (boost::weak_ptr<std::string>)> Callback;
std::list<Callback> callbacks;
Callback func;
callbacks.remove(func); // This causes the error
```

Comment: Even if you do decide to go with this, you probably want `vector` rather than `list`...

Comment: @Billy I don't know in which order the callbacks might be removed, so a list is better in this case.

Comment: In almost all real world cases, `vector` still wins due to cache locality and reduced overhead on the memory allocator. `list` will be slower unless it is exceedingly (tens or hundreds of thousands of elements) long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `std::list<T>::remove`, it looks for the value to remove by comparing it to the elements in the list. In the case of `boost::function` objects, this fails because `boost::function` objects can't be compared. See [Why can't I compare boost::function objects with operator== or operator!=](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/function/faq.html#id1381839) in the Boost Function FAQ.

You'll need to remove the objects from the list in another way (e.g. with `erase` and an iterator).

In this case, it looks like you're implementing something similar to the [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/signals.html) library. You may want to use that instead - it provides a way to register multiple callbacks and remove them.

Comment: Thank you. I looked around and found [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/function_equal.html); I can use it together with [remove_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/remove_if/) and Boost.Bind. Is there any reason for me to still use Boost.Signals?

Comment: @Paul: I'm not familiar with `function_equal`. According to the documentation it just returns `f == g` - I assume it actually does more than that or it would be pretty useless.

Comment: @interjay Considering, as you quoted, "boost::function objects can't be compared", then I consider function_equal to be pretty damn useful, allowing you to actually compare boost::function objects.

Comment: @leetNightshade: Except that it *doesn't* let you compare `boost::function` objects. It does let you compare Boost.Bind objects, which is apparently what the OP needed according to his comment.

Comment: @interjay Yeah I sadly realized that after further reading, but couldn't find this thread to adjust/remove my comment.